# Connect Excel to Survey123 Data Source

Tags: excel, arcgis-survey123

I have a form / survey created for Survey123. It has been published and I can access the data which has been captured through the ArcGIS Online Portal.

I would like to read the attribute information from this form in Excel. Similarly as I have connections to my SQL Databases and I can read the attribute information stored in the databases connected to my Collector for ArcGIS maps.

I know how to download the CSV / SHP / FGDB information, but I would like to connect to this information without the need to have a user logon to the AGOL and download it. Some users will not have ArcGIS Installed on their machines, so using Python is an option, but I cannot use `arcpy`.

Is there a workflow that will allow me to have a live connection between Excel and the attribute information stored in my Survey123 Form?

Comment: I think you can use the ArcGIS REST API as described here:
https://community.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2015/11/10/downloading-data-captured-with-survey123-for-arcgis

Comment: Great. Thanks I will give that a go. I am however hoping for a solution that won't require extra libraries to be installed on the users pcs.

Comment: You could always tweak the above solution and host it on your own web app. Parse the data as needed and then do something like this direct from excel?
http://www.windmill.co.uk/excel/excelweb.html
I suppose it depends how sensitive the data is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure your survey123 form with a webhook, so everytime data is submitted, a new record is added into an xls file hosted in Microsoft 365 or in a Google Spreadsheet.

In this way, you have a spreadsheet showing live data from Survey123 and people dont need anything extra to look at the data.

You can learn more about webhooks in survey123 here

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/browser/analyze-results/webhooks.htm

And here:

https://community.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2018/07/19/automating-workflows-with-survey123-and-microsoft-flow

Microsoft Flow, Zapier, Integromat... are all great options with connectors that let you work with spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to AGOL from Excel using Power Query. Under the **Data** tab, click **Get Data** then choose **Launch Power Query Editor**
On the far right, click **New Source** and choose **Other Source** then choose **Blank Query**
Now click **Advanced Editor**

If your Survey is not public then you will first need to get an authorization token. Paste the following M code and replace with your credentials.

```
let
    GetJson = Web.Contents("https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/generateToken/", [Headers=[Accept="application/json", #"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"], Query=[referer = "https://www.arcgis.com", f = "pjson"], Content=Text.ToBinary("username=####YOUR USENAME###&password=###YOUR PASSWORD###")]),
    FormatAsJson = Json.Document(GetJson),
    token = FormatAsJson[token],
```

Next you will use this token to query the hosted feature layer from your survey and convert it into a table. The Feature Service URL for your Hosted Feature Layer is found in the bottom right of the Overview Page.
EG for **Cellular Towers in the United States** the Overview page is: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=15dabb4108254481b591018be2598f3c#overview and the Service URL in the bottom right is: https://services1.arcgis.com/Hp6G80Pky0om7QvQ/arcgis/rest/services/Cellular_Towers/FeatureServer/0
There's even a copy button!

```
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(Text.Combine({"###YOUR HOSTED FEATURE LAYER FEATURESERVICE URL###/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&resultType=none&distance=0.0&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&returnGeodetic=false&outFields=*&returnHiddenFields=false&returnGeometry=true&featureEncoding=esriDefault&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&defaultSR=&datumTransformation=&applyVCSProjection=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnUniqueIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnQueryGeometry=false&returnDistinctValues=false&cacheHint=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&having=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=true&quantizationParameters=&sqlFormat=none&f=pjson&token=", token}))),
    fields = Source[fields],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(fields, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"name", "type", "alias", "sqlType", "domain", "defaultValue"}, {"name", "type", "alias", "sqlType", "domain", "defaultValue"}),
    #"Filter for Domains" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Column1", each ([domain] <> null)),
    #"Expand Domains" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Filter for Domains", "domain", {"type", "name", "codedValues"}, {"domain.type", "domain.name", "domain.codedValues"}),
    #"Expanded Domain Coded Values" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expand Domains", "domain.codedValues"),
    #"Unpivot Coded Values" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Domain Coded Values", "domain.codedValues", {"name", "code"}, {"domain.codedValues.name", "domain.codedValues.code"}),
    #"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivot Coded Values",{{"name", "Field Domain"}, {"domain.codedValues.name", "Domain Name"}, {"domain.codedValues.code", "Domain Code"}}),
    #"Domain Coded Value" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns3",{"Field Domain", "Domain Code", "Domain Name"}),
    #"Expanded Column2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"name", "type", "alias", "sqlType", "domain", "defaultValue", "length"}, {"name", "type", "alias", "sqlType", "domain", "defaultValue", "length"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Column2",{"type", "sqlType", "domain", "defaultValue", "length"}),
    #"Column Names Lookup List" = Table.ToRows(#"Removed Columns"),
    features = Source[features],
    #"Converted to Table1" = Table.FromList(features, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column3" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table1", "Column1", {"geometry"}, {"geometry"}),
    #"Expanded geometry" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column3", "geometry", {"x", "y"}, {"x", "y"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded geometry", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Expanded Column4" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table1", "Column1", {"attributes"}, {"attributes"})
in
    #"Expanded Column4"
```

Once you've replaced the ###PLACEHOLDERS### from my example code with your parameters click **Done**
You will now need to expand the single column of **Records** into a table by clicking to the right of the column name. It's a button with two opposite arrows. Click **OK** and you will see your data.
Now click **Close & Load**
You will now see a worksheet with the same name as the query you just made with your data in it. You can refresh your data by clicking the Refresh All button on the **Data** tab or configure the query to **Refresh data when opening the file** in the properties of the query in the **Queries & Connections** window.

PS - this also works for Power BI

Good Luck!